# Mongoose get only specific object from array or empty array if there is none

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have a **questionnaire** model:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  category: String,
  description: String,
  requirementOption: String,
  creationDate: String,
  questions: [],
  answers: []
})
```

As you can see the answers is an array. This array contains object that have this structure

```
{
  "participantEmail": "someEmail@email.email"      
  "currentIndex": 14,
  ...
}
```

Now I want to get a specific questionnaire by id, but in answers array I only want specific participant email. So the answers array should have either one element or no element. But I don't want to get `null` result if there is no such email in the answers array.

I figure it out how to get that specific element from array with this query:

```
dbModel.findOne({_id: id, 'answers': {$elemMatch: {participantEmail: "someEmail@email.com"}}}, {'answers.$': 1}).exec();
```

And if that email exists in the answer array I will get this:

```
 "data": {
    "questionnaireForParticipant": {
      "id": "5d9ca298cba039001b916c55",
      "title": null,
      "category": null,
      "creationDate": null,
      "description": null,
      "questions": null,
      "answers": [
        {
          "participantEmail": "someEmail@email.com",
          ....
         }

    }
  }
```

But if that email is not in the answers array I will get only `null`. Also I would like to get the `title` and `category` and all of the other fields. But I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: Did I get it right? Do you want to get **all** documents which have an answer by specific email **OR** do not have an answer at all

Comment: @VaheYavrumian I updated the question to make it a bit more clear

Comment: At first, there is only one document with specific [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)(_id) in entire collection, so you simply don't need other filters, you can just get that one doc with Model.findById(_id) and do other validations in your code

Comment: @VaheYavrumian ok, got it, but what if I want to update only a specific answer, what query should I use for that?

Comment: I think the best way will be getting document by any query you want, then making changes in your code and then saving doc with `doc.save()`, I think this will be easier than editing doc with _Update_ query

Comment: That's the way I was doing it, but now I'm facing a problem if multiple users update at the same time I get wrong data in answers array, that's why I want to update specific answer, or add a new one if it does not exist

Comment: @LorinczAlexandru : When you say *get only specific object from array or empty array if there is none* do you mean empty array on `answers` field or empty array as result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've this condition `'answers': {$elemMatch: {participantEmail: "someEmail@email.com"}}` in filter part of `.findOne()` - If for given `_id` document there are no elements in `answers. participantEmail` array match with input value `"someEmail@email.com"` then `.findOne()` will return `null` as output. So if you wanted to return document irrespective of a matching element exists in `answers` array or not then try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000") }
  },
  /** addFields will re-create an existing field or will create new field if there is no field with same name */
  {
    $addFields: {
      answers: {
        $filter: { // filter will result in either [] or array with matching elements
          input: "$answers",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.participantEmail", "someEmail@email.com" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4FWuDTM-YOU)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

**Note :** We've used aggregation as you wanted to return either `answers` array with matched element or an empty array. Also you can use `$project` instead of `$addFields` to transform the output as you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you, that's it

Comment: @LorinczAlexandru : Just as note - Using above query you definitely get the doc out but when it comes to `answers` array either it can be empty `[]` if no match is found or will have matching object/objects like `[{...}]`. If you don't need that field at all in the response document then you can simply use `$elemMatch` in projection as stated..

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, but if you are using mongoose like I do this is how you have to write the accepted answer query:

```
      dbModel.aggregate([
          { 
            $match: { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000") } 
          }]).addFields({
            answers: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$answers",
                  cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.participantEmail", "someEmail@email.com" ] }
              }
            }
          }).exec();
```

Comment: Yes in mongoose you would do `.aggregate()` on mongoose model `dbModel` & has to call `.exec()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

With this sample ***input document***:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  title: "t-1",
  category: "cat-abc",
  creationDate: ISODate("2020-05-05T07:01:09.853Z"),
  questions: [ ],
  answers: [
      { participantEmail: "someEmail@email.email", currentIndex: 14 }
  ]
}
```

And, with this ***query***:

```
EMAIL_TO_MATCH = "someEmail@email.email"

db.questionnaire.findOne( 
  { _id: 1 }, 
  { title: 1, category: 1, answers: { $elemMatch: { participantEmail: EMAIL_TO_MATCH } } } 
)
```

The query returns (when the `answers.participantEmail` matches):

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "title" : "t-1",
        "category" : "cat-abc",
        "answers" : [
                {
                        "participantEmail" : "someEmail@email.email",
                        "currentIndex" : 12
                }
        ]
}
```

And, when the `answers.participantEmail` *doesn't* match *or* if the `amswers` array is *empty*, the result is:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "title" : "t-1", "category" : "cat-abc" }
```

**NOTE**: The [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) used in the above query is a *projection* operator.